# Get multiple persistent entries by keylist

Tags: sql, haskell

I use SQLite with persistent in Haskell.

I have a list of keys i.e. `[PostId]`.
Now I want to get all entries
`[Desc PostCrtDate, OffsetBy from, LimitTo (to - from + 1)]`.

Is there an alternative to `selectList` but with a list of keys instead of or in addition to the "normal" conditions of a SQL query?

It seems horribly inefficient to use `mapM get keyList` and then do sorting/offsetting/limiting, especially with a big database.

I am open to using esqueleto if necessary but I would rather not introduce another dependency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on a mobile right now and therefore may get the syntax wrong, but it's something like:

```
selectWhere [PostId <-. IdList] []
```

That operator is the "in" operator, checking if a value is in a list.

Note that this will not give any errors if some of the keys are not found, you'd need to check for that manually.

Comment: ah yes I missed that operator. Small correction: ```selectList``` instead of ```selectWhere``` and ```IdList``` lower-case since it's not a type in this case. thanks.